# PhotoImage in function with PIL Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I hope you're weel guys.

I'm a novice in developpement, and i'm trying to make a window with button and a picture.

But i get an error and i don't know why. I've tried my code outside a function and it works well, but when it's inside my function, img seems to not get path.

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk





def MainScreen():
    main_screen = Tk()
    main_screen.geometry("700x450")
    main_screen.title("Gestion")
    canvas = Canvas(main_screen)
    canvas.pack()
    image_info = PIL.Image.open(r"C:/Users/etc...")
    img = PhotoImage(width=700, height=450)
    image_info = image_info.resize((100, 100), PIL.Image.BOX)
    image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_info)
    PhotoImage(master=canvas, width=300, height=200)
    canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor=NW, image=image)
    canvas.place(x=350, y=300)

def ConnexionMainScreen():
    receptusername = username.get()
    receptpassword = password.get()
    if receptusername == "D":
        if receptpassword == "A":
            MainScreen()
            login_screen.destroy()


def LoginScreen():
    global username
    global password
    global login_screen
    login_screen = Tk()
    login_screen.geometry("300x400")
    login_screen.title("Connexion")
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    Label(login_screen, text="Page de connexion", bg="grey", width=20, height=2, font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text='').pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Identifiant").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text='').pack()
    Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text='').pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="Mot de passe").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text='').pack()
    Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text='').pack()
    Button(login_screen, text='Connexion',height = 2, command=ConnexionMainScreen).pack()
    login_screen.mainloop()


LoginScreen()
```

And here's the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\test connaissance2.py", line 28, in ConnexionMainScreen
    MainScreen()
  File "PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\test connaissance2.py", line 20, in MainScreen
    canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor=NW, image=image)
  File "Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2787, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2773, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Two big issues:

1. You should never have more than one instance of Tk() open. You need to quit (not just destroy) the first one before opening the second one.

   ```
    if receptpassword == "A":
        login_screen.quit()
        MainScreen()
   ```

   Or (probably better), you could remake the screen instead of closing it and making a new one.
2. You need to explicitly keep the image object. See the note here: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

   ```
    def MainScreen():
        main_screen = Tk()
        main_screen.geometry("700x450")
        main_screen.title("Gestion")
        canvas = Canvas(main_screen)
        canvas.pack()
        image_info = PIL.Image.open(r"C:/Users/etc...")
        image_info = image_info.resize((100, 100), PIL.Image.BOX)
        image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_info)
        canvas.create_image((0, 0), anchor=NW, image=image)
        canvas.img = image # <== code to keep the reference
        canvas.place(x=350, y=300)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for you knowledge ! I got an new error, i'm going to resolve it by myself. Thanks again !

Comment: Using `login_screen.quit()` will only exit the `mainloop()` but without destroying `login_screen`.  So same exception will be raised when `MainScreen()` is executed due to multiple instances of `Tk()`.